# Nuget - is reinstalling packages marked with requireReinstallation problem neccessary?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

After upgrading a VS solution to a new .Net version NuGet sometimes adds requireReinstallation flag to third-party packages in packages.config, which results in a build warnings.

This issue has been described in this post:
https://dhalgara.com/2018/04/19/nuget-require-reinstallation/

I wonder if it's safe to skip reinstalling packages marked with requireReinstallation flag in packages.config if I get no warnings while building the solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder if it's safe to skip reinstalling packages marked with requireReinstallation flag in packages.config if I get no warnings while building the solution?

Not sure to tell you if this is safe to skip reinstalling packages marked with `requireReinstallation` flag in packages.config if you get no warnings while building the solution, but personal recommendation not to skip the re-installation.

According to the [release notes](http://blog.nuget.org/20130814/nuget-2.7-release-candidate.html):

> If we detect that any of your packages were affected by the
>   retargeting or upgrade, we’ll produce immediate build errors to let
>   you know. In addition to the immediate build error, we also persist a
>   requireReinstallation="true" flag in your packages.config file for all
>   packages that were affected by the retargeting, and each subsequent
>   build in Visual Studio will raise a build warnings for those packages.

That means the algorithm is the same as the algorithm that is used to determine which assembly is the best match for the project if the NuGet package was to be installed into the project if it had the new target framework. If the assembly is different then NuGet considers that a re-installation is required. For example, nuget package with:

- lib/net45

  - Classlibeary1.dll
- lib/net46

  - Classlibeary1.dll

When you change you target framework from .net 4.5 to 4.6, then NuGet would mark dll under .net 46 as needing reinstallation. package has an assembly that targets .NET 4.6 so it is considered a better match.

If the method you referenced from .net 46 and .net 45 are the same, it is safe to skip reinstalling packages marked with requireReinstallation flag, but if the method is different in the .net 46 and .net 45, you need to reinstall this nuget package.

So, personal recommendation not to skip the re-installation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: how to do the reinstallation with VS4Mac?